# jongo find subdocuments with array of values

Tags: mongodb, jongo

My data looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("53a173630364206735975b35"),
"username" : "TestUserID",
"resources" : [
    {
        "id" : "FirstTestResourceId",
        "tags" : [
            "TestResourceTag1",
            "TestResourceTag2"
        ],
    }
    {
        "id" : "SecondTestResourceId",
        "tags" : [
            "TestResourceTag1",
            "TestResourceTag2"
        ],
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is retrieve all the resource documents for a user where any of the tags match any member of an array of Strings.

When I do:

```
db.collection.find({username: 'TestUserID', 'resources.tags': { $in: ['TestResourceTag1']}})
```

it seems to work fine (as in it brings back the correct document with the correct resource subdocument, but when I try it in my java class it brings back nada.

```
Iterable<Resource> resources = userCollection.find("{username: #, 'resources.tags': { $in: #}}", userID, tags).as(Resource.class);
```

Where userID = String and tags = String[]

I guess I'm doing something dim in the query, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'd be most grateful for any guidance with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<String>` instead of an array of String for your `tags` variable, so instead of

```
String[] tags = new String[]{"TestResourceTag1"};
```

try using

```
List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("TestResourceTag1");
```

Hope this helps.